# Maven assembly interaction

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I now have 3 projects and they are Core, Client and Utility, where both Core and Client will be depended on Utility. For now my goal is to create two assemblies as following...

```
First one:

Core-Assembly   
|   
|---- Core.jar     
|---- Utility.jar      
|---- Client.jar      


Second one:

NoAction-Assembly  
|  
|---- all the xml and properties files
```

I want to separate all the configurations from the code base and store them in another assembly so that people only need to modify the configurations in the NoAction-Assembly and leave Core-Assembly untouched. Is there any ways that I can achieve that? Thank you!

Comment: You want the core assembly to inherit the assembly descriptor settings from the noaction assembly?

Comment: sorry, i just modified my question. Do you think I can create a bundle assembly in order to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Core assembly, if it only contains jars, doesn't need to be an assembly.  There will simply be a dependencies element in the noaction assembly that pulls in those jars for you.

You will have a maven project for each of the jars; each of those project/builds will produce it's respective jar.  Then the single assembly project, no action, will reference those jars via the "dependencies" element of the assembly descriptor.